# turning a text format into a date format with sas

Tags: sas

I have the following :

```
data a_test;
input date $;
cards;
2013M10
2013M11
2013M12
2014M1
;
run;
```

The dates are in a text format , not dates.

How would you do to change them in a date format like `Dec 2013`?

I was thinking of removing the M and put instead a / or just leave as a space.

Any insights would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MDY function to convert the text to dates.

```
data a_test;
input date $;
new_date=mdy(substr(date,6,2),01,substr(date,1,4));
format new_date monyy5.;
cards;
2013M10
2013M11
2013M12
2014M1
;
run;
```